# Are there LEGO Hygrometer sensors?

Tags: mindstorms, sensor

Currently, there are light, ultrasonic, touch and sound Mindstorms sensors, but is there a hygrometer sensor from LEGO?

Comment: Is this for a specific version or any Mindstorm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not one made by LEGO. However, there are a number of 3rd-party options:

- [Fatcatlab](http://fatcatlab.com/) makes a [Humidity Sensor](http://fatcatlab.com/product/humidity-sensor/) (EV3 only).
- [Vernier](http://www.vernier.com) makes a [relative humidity sensor](http://www.vernier.com/products/sensors/rh-bta/) that can be used with the [Vernier sensor adapter](http://www.vernier.com/products/interfaces/bta-nxt/) (EV3 and NXT).
- There are also several [temperature and humidity sensors from Grove](http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/wiki/GROVE_System#Environmental_Monitoring) that can be used with the [mindsensors.com Grove sensor adapter](http://www.mindsensors.com/ev3-and-nxt/20-grove-sensor-adapter-for-ev3-or-nxt) (EV3 and NXT).